# How to do a function that will return me to main menu from any place of program?

Tags: c++

How to do a function that will clean screen and return me to a main menu of program even during entering elements of matrix. And how to disable pressing other keys except arrows and Enter during navigating the menu?

**This is my C++ code:**

```
    while(running)
    {
        gotoXY(18,1);  cout << "Main Menu";
        gotoXY(20,3);  cout << " Enter matrix";
        gotoXY(20,4);  cout << " Randomize matrix";
        gotoXY(20,5);  cout << " Exit";

        system("pause>nul"); // the >nul bit causes it the print no message

        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT)) //down button pressed
            {
                gotoXY(18,pos); cout << "  ";
                pos++;
                gotoXY(18,pos); cout << "->";
                menu_item++;
                if (pos == 6)
                    {
                        gotoXY(18,pos); cout << "  ";
                        pos = 3;
                        gotoXY(18,3); cout << "->";
                        menu_item = 0;
                    }
                continue;

            }

        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) || GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT)) //up button pressed
            {
                gotoXY(18,pos); cout << "  ";
                pos--;
                gotoXY(18,pos); cout << "->";
                menu_item--;
                if (pos == 2)
                    {
                        gotoXY(18,pos); cout << "  ";
                        pos = 5;
                        gotoXY(18,5); cout << "->";
                        menu_item = 2;
                    }
                continue;
            }



        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN)){ // Enter key pressed

            switch(menu_item){

                case 0: {

                    gotoXY(20,10);
                    int i, j, n;
                    double **a, *b;
                    cout << "Enter NUMBER of equations: ";
                    cin >> n;



                    a = (double **)malloc(n*sizeof(double));
                    b = (double *)malloc(n*sizeof(double));

                    cout << "Enter Matrix A\n";
                    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    {
                        a[i] = (double *)malloc(n*sizeof(double));
                        //Ввод a
                        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
                        {
                            cout <<"a["<< i + 1 << "][" << j + 1 << "] = ";
                            //cin >>a[i][j];
                            a[i][j] = proverkafloat();
                        }
                    }

                    cout << "\tSee input\r\n";
                    cout << "Matrix A:\r\n";
                    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    {
                        cout << "|\t";
                        ShowVector(n, a[i]);
                    };


                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "Enter Vector B\n";
                    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    {
                        cout << "b[" << i + 1 << "] = ";
                        cin >> b[i]
                    }

                    cout << "\n\n";
                    cout << "\tSee input\r\n";
                    cout << "\n";
                    cout << "Vector B:\r\n";
                    cout << "|\t";
                    ShowVector(n, b);


                    system("pause");
                    system("CLS");
                    gotoXY(18,pos); cout << "->";
                    break;
                }

                case 1:
                  {
                    gotoXY(20,10);
                    int i, j;
                    double **a, *b, n;
                    cout << "Enter NUMBER of equations: ";
                    cin >> n;

                    srand(time(0));
                    a = (double **)malloc(n*sizeof(double));
                    b = (double *)malloc(n*sizeof(double));
                    //Randomizing Matrix A
                    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    {
                        a[i] = (double *)malloc(n*sizeof(double));
                        //Ввод a
                        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
                        {
                          a[i][j] = (double)(rand() % 100 + (-50))/((double)(rand() % 100 + (-50)));
                        }
                    }

                    cout << "\tSee input\r\n";
                    cout << "Matrix A:\r\n";
                    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    {
                        cout << "|\t";
                        ShowVector(n, a[i]);
                    };


                    //Randomizing Vector B
                    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    {

                        b[i] = (double)(rand() % 100 + (-50))/((double)(rand() % 100 + (-50)));
                    }

                    cout << "\n\n";
                    cout << "\tSee input\r\n";
                    cout << "\n";
                    cout << "Vector B:\r\n";
                    cout << "|\t";
                    ShowVector(n, b);


                    system("pause");
                    system("CLS");
                    gotoXY(18,pos); cout << "->";
                    break;
                  }

                case 2:
                        {
                            gotoXY(20,10);
                            cout << "The program has now terminated!!";
                            running = false;
                            getch();
                        }

            }

        }

    }

    gotoXY(20,21);
    return 0;
}

void gotoXY(int x, int y)
    {
        CursorPosition.X = x;
        CursorPosition.Y = y;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(console,CursorPosition);
    }

void ShowVector(int n, double * vec)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << vec[i] << "  ";
        cout << "\t";
        cout << "|";
        cout << "\r\n";
    }
```

Comment: Its unlikely anyone would read the entire code or even try to answer the question by reading it. Editing the question to filter the essential parts of your code might help

Comment: you should really review [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to pair your code down to the essance of the question.

Comment: I tried to edit it. I hope it looks better.

Comment: What's wrong with your code?  The code looks like the `while(running)` loop should be redrawing your menu.

Comment: Yes, it redraws my menu. Maybe you can advise a better way to realize my menu?

Answer (score 0):

The best method to "return" from a canceled menu processing function is to return.

One issue may be stack unwinding.  When the main menu processing function calls a function for menu selection process, it pushes the return address on the stack.  If the selection processing function fails or needs to return quickly, it can't use a `goto` because there will still be that return address on the stack.  This issue is more pronounced when you have nested menus.

This is similar to error handling and catching.  You could try having a `catch` statement in your main menu function.